# Is this the easiest calculus exercise ever?

Tags: calculus, axioms

I have a series of exercises to do, but one of these seems to be really easy to do, that it even seems strange to be asked to do.

The exercise is:

> Use only the field axioms to show that:
>
> $$(x + y)(x - y) = (x \cdot x) - (y \cdot y)$$
>
> for any $x$, $y$ $\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Well, without using the field axioms, we can immediately say that the statement it's true.

Can we simply use the *distributivity* field axiom:

$$x\cdot (y + z) = (x\cdot y) + (x \cdot z)$$

to demonstrate the equality, or maybe I am jumping important passages and I am not showing all the steps to achieve the result?

---

I did it like this:

1. Replace $(x + y)$ with a $k$, since addition is closed for $\mathbb{Q}$:
   $$k(x - y)$$
2. Use *distributivity* field with $k$
   $$k \cdot x - k \cdot y$$
3. Replace $k$ with the original value $(x + y)$

   $$(x + y) \cdot x - ((x + y) \cdot y)$$
4. Use *distributivity* field for the first and second subtrahend (can we say subtrahend?)

$$(x \cdot x + y \cdot x) - (x \cdot y + y \cdot y) = x \cdot x + y \cdot x - x \cdot y - y \cdot y =  x \cdot x - y \cdot y$$

If this is not correct, could you tell me why?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21351/discussion-on-question-by-rinzler-is-this-the-easiest-calculus-exercise-ever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work is good, but note that in the last step you use the property:
$ y\cdot x =x \cdot y$ to eliminate two terms. So to find the result you need commutativity of the product, that is a typical property requested for a field. In a non commutative ring the identity $(x+y)(x-y)=x^2-y^2$ is not valid.